# C++: Why re-input stringstream doesn't work? the content remains the same

Tags: stream, stringstream

I am trying to understand the details of the stringstream in C++. But I find a trouble when I tried to re-input ("<<") the stringstream object. (i.e. the content of the obj still remains the same.) My code is as follows. Outputs are shown in comments.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    stringstream sso;
    cout <<"orginal: " << sso.str() <<endl; //orginal:"empty"
    sso << "A" << " " << "B" << " " << "C";
    cout <<"flowin:" << sso.str() <<endl; //flowin:A B C

    string r1, r2, r3;
    sso >> r1 >> r2 >> r3;
    cout << "flowout:" << r1 << r2 << r3 << endl;//flowout:ABC
    cout << "base: " << sso.str() << endl; //base: A B C

    cout << "----problem here-----" << endl;
    sso << "D" << " " << "E" << " " << "F";
    cout <<"flowin:" << sso.str() <<endl; //flowin:A B C

    cout << "----this works-----" << endl;
    sso.clear(); //clear flag
    sso.str(""); //clear content
    sso << "D" << " " << "E" << " " << "F";
    cout <<"flowin:" << sso.str() <<endl; //flowin:D E F

    return 0;
}
```

Why? I don't understand the result in "---problem here---". Why doesn't the sso accept new inputs?

Apprecited,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last read of `sso >> r1 >> r2 >> r3;` puts the stream into fail state because no more characters were available while it was still trying to read more characters for `r3`.

In fail state the stream cannot be written to or read from.  To fix your problem move `sso.clear();` up to before `sso << "D"`.

You can see different behaviour if you output an extra space after `C` because then the stream does not enter fail state (it successfully reads `r3` while there is still the space in the stream).