# What is the return value of "stringstream>>something"?

Tags: c++, stringstream

What is the return value of the `stringstream >> something`?  For example, the return value of `stringstream_obj >> int_obj`. I understand the return type is still the stream because of `istream& operator>> (int& val)`. But what's the value? To be specific, here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
    stringstream sss(string("0"));
    int num;
    if (sss >> num) // don't understand here
        cout << "true" << endl;
    else 
        cout << "false" << endl;
    //output "true"    
    return 0;
}
```

As the comment, why is the output true? The sss contains only 1 character. Once "sss >> num", the returned "stringstream" should have empty content thus the value of the bracket should be false.

Appreciated,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`operator>>` returns a reference to the stream, as you said. Then, in the context of the `if` the stream is converted to a `bool` through the [conversion operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) which gives :

> true if the stream has no errors, false otherwise.

You successfully read the '0' so the stream has no errors, try reading one again and you'll see the stream has errors and `if(sss)` evaluates to `false`.

Comment: Thanks @GillBates. Here I am kind of confused by the fail state of stringstream and error of it. Since the content of sss is "drained" by "sss >> num", the sss enters the fail state which blocks further usage of this stream object. Is fail state considered to be an error? Or how are they different?

Comment: @leonardo_zz - The read succeeded in extracting a number, so it did not fail. The fact that it also reached eof can be checked by `sss.eof()` but is in itself not an error.

Comment: Thanks@BoPersson. I understand that the read succeeded in extracting "0". What confused me is the term "fail state" of the stringstream, as shown in [the fail state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41627448/c-why-re-input-stringstream-doesnt-work-the-content-remains-the-same). The fail state is triggered once the content of the stringstream is drained (i.e. eof is reached.), although the last character is extracted successfully. In the fail state, the stringstream cannot be written anymore. It seems that this fail state is not considered to be an error. Am I correct? Appreciated

Comment: Reaching the end of the stream does NOT set the fail state automatically.  It simply ends the current read. If that's valid for the current type, then it's a success state. If that's invalid for the current type, then it sets the fail bit.  `sss >> num` will read in 0, hit the end, and that's valid, so it's not a failure state. If you executed `sss >> num` a second time, it'd be at the end without reading anything, which isn't valid, so _that_ would set the fail bit.

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes friend that's what I mean with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In c++ in general when `>>` is used with streams it returns itself

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/

In your case operator>> that does `sss >> num` returns `sss`

(I am assuming you are using c++11 which it looks like)

And then your sss aka stringstream has a [bool operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/)
which returns true if the conversion was successful

so in summary the if statement is more like

```
if( convert sss to int and check if successful)
// success
else
// fail
```

This is good discussion you can read 
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/6046/